# Conversion double array to byte array

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

How do I convert a `double[]` array to a `byte[]` array and vice versa?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sizeof(double));
        Console.WriteLine(double.MaxValue);

        double[] array = new double[] { 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0 };
        byte[] convertedarray = ?

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the conversion of the value (ie. `10.0` -> 10) or the eight bytes of the underlying machine representation (eg. for serialisation)?

Comment: What sort of conversion are we talking about here?  You want to take the corresponding double and "cast" it to an integral type to get the byte value?  Or do you want to get the byte representation of each of the double values?  You need to _clarify_.

Comment: intention is to use BinaryWriter.Write() function. But this accepts only bytes. I want to  get the byte representation of each of the double values?

Comment: @Raghaav: In that case you want the byte representation of each double.

Comment: Yes. How to do this? The array size will be 1,00,000

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Assuming you want the doubles placed in the corresponding byte array one after the other, LINQ can make short work out of this:

```
static byte[] GetBytes(double[] values)
{
    return values.SelectMany(value => BitConverter.GetBytes(value)).ToArray();
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `Buffer.BlockCopy()`:

```
static byte[] GetBytesAlt(double[] values)
{
    var result = new byte[values.Length * sizeof(double)];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(values, 0, result, 0, result.Length);
    return result;
}
```

To convert back:

```
static double[] GetDoubles(byte[] bytes)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, bytes.Length / sizeof(double))
        .Select(offset => BitConverter.ToDouble(bytes, offset * sizeof(double)))
        .ToArray();
}

static double[] GetDoublesAlt(byte[] bytes)
{
    var result = new double[bytes.Length / sizeof(double)];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, result, 0, bytes.Length);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The BlockCopy version is great. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `Select` and `ToArray` methods to convert one array to another:

```
oneArray = anotherArray.Select(n => {
  // the conversion of one item from one type to another goes here
}).ToArray();
```

To convert from double to byte:

```
byteArray = doubleArray.Select(n => {
  return Convert.ToByte(n);
}).ToArray();
```

To convert from byte to double you just change the conversion part:

```
doubleArray = byteArray.Select(n => {
  return Convert.ToDouble(n);
}).ToArray();
```

---

If you want to convert each double to a multi-byte representation, you can use the `SelectMany` method and the `BitConverter` class. As each double will result in an array of bytes, the `SelectMany` method will flatten them into a single result.

```
byteArray = doubleArray.SelectMany(n => {
  return BitConverter.GetBytes(n);
}).ToArray();
```

To convert back to doubles, you would need to loop the bytes eight at a time:

```
doubleArray = Enumerable.Range(0, byteArray.Length / 8).Select(i => {
  return BitConverter.ToDouble(byteArray, i * 8);
}).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Bitconverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) class.

Answer (score 2):

```
double[] array = new double[] { 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0 };
byte[] convertedarray = array.Select(x => Convert.ToByte(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: how to convert byte[] back to double[].

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx) method.

Look at the pages example, you will clearly understand.

```
doubleArray = byteArray.Select(n => {return Convert.ToDouble(n);}).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this, I think:

```
byte[] byteArray = new byteArray[...];  
...
byteArray.SetValue(Convert.ToByte(d), index);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var byteArray = (from d in doubleArray
                 select (byte)d)
                .ToArray();

var doubleArray = (from b in byteArray
                   select (double)b)
                  .ToArray();
```

Cheers.

Comment: This will remove some data from big doubles.

Comment: @VMAtm: Though not a reason to condemn him for this.  Other answers here have the same problem only because it wasn't clear in the first place.