# FFT implementation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, fft

I have a problem with implementing FFT. The target device is Windows Phone 7.

This is how i'm doing it.
buffer is a byte array with fixed size 1024.

```
var o = Observable.FromEvent<EventArgs>(Microphone.Default, "BufferReady");
        o.Subscribe(evt =>
        {
            double[] dImageArray = this.buffer.Select(i => Convert.ToDouble(i)).ToArray();

            fftoutput = Saluse.MediaKit.Sample.FourierTransform.FFTDb(ref dImageArray);

        });
```

The class i'm using(as you can see) is from SaluseMediakit ([source](http://wklej.org/id/657262/))

Is this the right path? Or i'm somewhere mistaken?

Comment: I have a problem with implementing FFT. - Then describe the problem. Include details (compiler errors, exception details, ...)

Comment: It's about the fftoutput. I don't know how to verify the result. Is it proper or not. The byte array from the mikrophone, do i convert it properly?

Comment: `i'm somewhere mistaken?` Yes, if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I've manage to perform a good FFT, with AFORGE(this library saved me several times). The proper way to obtain the waveform info from the mic.

```
  double[] sampleBuffer = new double[buffer.Length / 2];
            int h = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i += 2)
            {
                sampleBuffer[h] = Convert.ToDouble(BitConverter.ToInt16((byte[])buffer, i));
                h++;
            }
```

Following up with another Question. I would love to make a visual equalizer. But I have no idea how-to.

Comment: You get data from microphone (byte[]) convert it to double[] made some changes with AFortge. Could you describe how you convert your data back (double[]->byte[])?

Comment: Looks like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952923/conversion-double-array-to-byte-array is answer.