# How to store an array of doubles, into a varbinary datatype, to a database?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database, ado.net

I have a objects which I want to store onto a database table.  The table entries is comprised of all the attributes of this object.  One of these attributes is an array of doubles.  This array may vary per object from about 4,000 to 100,000 values.  I previously tried to create two tables, one for the majority of the attributes and the other that contains these double values.  Then create a relationship between the two.  I realized that when I transfer the object to the tables it takes a considerable amount of time to get the points onto the second table.  That's like thousands of queries per object.  So, my second plan is to take this array of doubles and put them all in a varbinary(max) entry in the table.

I have gotten responses that this is possible but I don't understand how to do it.

Comment: Easiest way to do this would be to convert your double array to a byte array and then just store the byte array into your varbinary field.  See this answer for way to convert double array to byte array..  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6953111/1181408.  If you need help with the sql context see this answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4057802/1181408

Answer (score 1):

Under the presumption that you have written your doubles into a stream (in this case named _pictureContent), you write it out using AddWithValue as a sqlCommand parameter.

> command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PictureContent", _pictureContent);

To read it back in:

I stored the 'buffersize' as a separate column in the table, so when I read it I know whether I have anything in it or not.  If I do, I use GetBytes to read the varbinary column.

> long bufferSize = dataReader.IsDBNull(FIELD_BUFFERSIZE) ? 0 : dataReader.GetInt64(FIELD_BUFFERSIZE);
>   if (bufferSize > 0)
>   {
>      j.PictureContent = new byte[bufferSize];
>      bufferSize = dataReader.GetBytes(FIELD_PICTURECONTENT, 0, _pictureContent, 0, Convert.ToInt32(bufferSize));
>   }

FIELD_PICTURECONTENT is the offset in the incoming collection of columns (i.e., the 5th column), the first 0 is the starting location to read from in the incoming stream, _picture content is the target byte array, the second 0 is the offset to write to in the bytearray, and (buffersize) is the number of bytes to read.