# How to write an array of doubles to a file very fast in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to write something like this to a file:

```
FileStream output = new FileStream("test.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
BinaryWriter binWtr = new BinaryWriter(output);
double [] a = new double [1000000];  //this array fill complete

for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    binWtr.Write(a[i]);
}
```

And unfortunately this code's process last very long!
(in this example about 10 seconds!)

The file format is binary.

How can I make that faster?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to speed up the process by converting your array of doubles to an array of bytes, and then write the bytes in one shot.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6953111/335858) shows how to do the conversion (the code below comes from that answer):

```
static byte[] GetBytes(double[] values) {
    var result = new byte[values.Length * sizeof(double)];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(values, 0, result, 0, result.Length);
    return result;
}
```

With the array of bytes in hand, [you can call `Write` that takes an array of bytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx149a0k(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var byteBuf = GetBytes(a);
binWtr.Write(byteBuf);
```

Comment: Or you can go `unsafe`, and safe a precious few cycles :D

Comment: Whilst technically correct it might be useful to explain WHY it is faster. Since if the OP needed to write 4GB worth of bytes, this certainly would not work.

Comment: @leppie I hope anyone doing that can supply the profiling results showing that it helped enough to justify enabling unsafe code in the project - because I bet it won't do much, not in this case :)

Comment: @romkyns My point is that it would be nice to give a deeper understanding of the problem at hand, WHY this is faster, and how to apply the lessons learnt.

Comment: @Aron and even if it were 4gb, you'd simply divide it into the biggest chunks that do work

Comment: @Mick that is EXACTLY my point. But the DEEPER point is WHY that works, and why you need to chunk it....>_< WHY should you in general chunk I/O operations.

Comment: @Aron oops, I missed the "if" in your comment. I've deleted mine.

Comment: @Aron I'd simply trial and measure to work that out, diving into docs would be the other way, there's always a bottleneck somewhere and regardless of how much documentation you've read, it's often a surprise where it is.

Comment: @Mick true, more generally one should use perf data to solve a perf problem. But, in a less general case, in almost all languages and situations, I/O adds significant latency, thus the number of operations should be kept to a minimum. On the other hand, manipulation of large data sets in memory is inefficient and costly. In the case of .net, there is also the LOH and GC to deal with. But its useful for all developers to knew these facts when approaching these problems. It is evident that the OP does know this, from the question.

Comment: @Aron: You would have to p/invoke `fwrite` too. This prevents the extra allocation of a byte buffer. You could also write to an `UnmanagedMemoryMappedFile`.

Answer (score 1):

You're writing the bytes 1 by 1, of course it's going to be slow.

You could do the writing in memory to an array and then write the array to disk all at once like this :

```
var arr = new double[1000000];
using(var strm = new MemoryStream())
using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(strm)) 
{ 
    foreach(var d in arr)
    {
        bw.Write(d);
    }
    bw.Flush();
    File.WriteAllBytes("myfile.bytes",strm.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: This might not be deserving of two downvotes anymore, but this isn't a great way of speeding up this particular task due to the unnecessary use of extra memory, so no upvote either...

Comment: @romkyns well aint that many ways to speed up something without knowing the issue but usually when something involve disk access and is slow, the best way to speed it up is to process it all at once, and the only way to process it all at once, is to have it all at once ready to be processed, which means memory allocated just for that, most of the time speed vs memory is a tradeof, can't get both