# How to quickly convert double[] into an byte[]

Tags: c#

I Have a very large array of doubles which contains image data, all the values are between 0 and 255.

In order to use BitmapSource.Create() I need an array of bytes. so I am converting all the data using:

`byte[] bytedata = doublearray.Select(X => Convert.ToByte(X)).ToArray();`

But I am finding this approach pretty slow, and it uses up all my processor time.

Does anyone have a recommendation as to the fastest way to extract the data from the double array and pass it into a byte array?

[Edit] It is the performance I am looking for, not just a the conversion. I also need to scrap the excess empty bytes, so:

`static byte[] GetBytes(double[] values)
{
    return values.SelectMany(value => BitConverter.GetBytes(value)).ToArray();
}`

doesn't work

Comment: A `for` loop and an explicit cast maybe?

Comment: Why is this in an array of doubles in the first place?

Comment: `Array.ConvertAll()` will be faster.

Comment: @SamIam - There's a number of cameras that dump out data like this for whatever reason.  Probably stored that way internally so the camera firmware can run transforms and other matrix math on it..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conversion double array to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952923/conversion-double-array-to-byte-array)

Comment: @FCin no, that question deals primarily with binary transfer of the actual raw double data, or at least most of the answers do.  Not all, but those answers aren't performance focused, either.

Comment: @zzxyz I don't think you will find anything faster than `Buffer.BlockCopy`, which basically does `memmove` internally.

Comment: @FCin And won't work for what he's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much to say about this other than obviously replace MessageBox with whatever output works for you.  The loop solution was about 10x faster on my system, in release and debug.  Edit:  Do note this code is potentially unsafe, of course.  You can always do `loopData[i] = (byte) ((int)doubleData[i] & 0xFF);` if there's any doubts about your source data.

```
    using System.Diagnostics;
    double[] doubleData = new double[500000];
    byte[] loopData;
    byte[] convertData;
    //linq approach
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    convertData = doubleData.Select(o => Convert.ToByte(o)).ToArray();
    MessageBox.Show(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());

    //loop approach
    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    loopData = new byte[doubleData.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i<doubleData.Length; ++i)
    {
        loopData[i] = (byte)(doubleData[i]);
    }
    MessageBox.Show(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
```