# How to send and receive a numpy array from python to Unity via socket

Tags: python, unity-game-engine

I am trying to send python array between python program and Unity3D.
Here is the python part to send a string message:

```
#send the message

import socket

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5065

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

msg = "Hello word!"

sock.sendto(msg, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))


#receive the message in Unity (C-sharp)

IPEndPoint anyIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), port);

byte[] data = client.Receive(ref anyIP); 

string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

I know that I can transform the numpy array to a string format and parse it to float in Unity. Is there any other elegant way to send and receive a numpy array instead of string?

Answer (score 1):

Since numpy's `ndarray` is a binary construct, you need a way to serialize it in Python, and de-serialize in C#.

For serialization, you can use [`ndarray.tobytes()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tobytes.html). To de-serialize, you must pay attention to the data type (double, int, etc.), and the machine's [Endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (little or big).

Also, if you are passing high-dimensional arrays, note the 'C' vs 'Fortran' capabilities of `ndarray.tobytes()`.

For example, in C#, you can deserialize an array of bytes to an array of doubles using `Buffer.BlockCopy()`, see, for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952923/conversion-double-array-to-byte-array) question.

Disclaimer: I haven't tried the above method myself.