# What method for live sending Python numpy data to Unity 3D?

Tags: python, c#, numpy, unity-game-engine, sockets

My goal for a project is to send some `Python` data ***live*** to `Unity 3D`.

More detailled: I'm processing a livestream webcam image for some values with `OpenCV` and `Numpy` and (ideally) want to send those calculated values continuously to Unity3D *while* the webcam and Python script is running. According to those sent values, a `GameObject` in Unity is then being live-transformed.

I got this to work only statically so far by using a `localhost` Python `socket` and C# `System.Net.Sockets`: When pressing a key while my Python script is running, the socket will open and send data. To receive, I then have to press a GUI button in Unity and afterwards the socket closes.

My problem: Using the socket in my Python `while`-loop while streaming the webcam makes my Python script freeze (found a workaround in my static idea for this freeze by sending random data back from Unity to Python), and I obviously also don't want to have to press a button in Unity everytime I want to receive anything.

My question: What method seems fit for my task to continuously send data from OpenCV (Python) to Unity? I don't really know what I should look into to be honest, and haven't found any similar issue on here so far. I heard about something like Python `UDP/TCP sockets` or C# `Thread`, is this something to go after? Or are `sockets` the thing to stick to and try to fix?

Comment: the freeze could be caused by either udp or encoding part. For udp, you could solve it by running async udp receiver, or via multi-trhead. For encoding performance, it would be much advanced, better try some existing unity plugins, as it usually takes you weeks/months for optimisation.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I will be trying async and/or multi-thread next. Maybe I'll get it to work with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this : “Take picture bytes stream from RenderTexture (Unity) and send it to python server on websockets”
A sample code you can use for connecting to websockets:

```
void Start() {
      ws = WebSocketFactory.CreateInstance("ws://localhost:12345");
      // ...
      
      // Connect to server 
      ws.connect();
   
     InvokeRepeating("Capture", 1f, 0.2f);
 }

 public void Capture() {
     RenderTexture activeRenderTexture = RenderTexture.active;
     RenderTexture.active = Camera.targetTexture;
     
     Camera.Render();
 
    Texture2D image = new Texture2D(Camera.targetTexture.width, Camera.targetTexture.height);
    image.ReadyPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Camera.targetTexture.width, CameraTexture.height), 0, 0);
    image.Apply();
    RenderTexture.active = activeRenderTexture;

    byte[] bytes = image.EncodeToPNG();
    Destroy(image);

    ws.send(bytes);
}
```

---

some important notes:

1- we encode images to PNG format and send them in this sample. you can do it or not, it's your choice!

2- In this solution, you are running everything on main thread in unity.Thus, it may lag and your program's frame rate may be low. also , the way you encode it is important (PNG encoding is huge!).

3- If this solution didn't work, you can also try streaming with FMETP STREAM maybe.

Comment: I think the op has bottleneck on both Python side and Unity side.
FMETP STREAM 3.0 latest demo is so awesome, it's compatible with streams from gstreamer and stereo pi, or unity stream to ffmpeg over udp with very common output format mjpeg.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think this is what I'm looking for, is it? I want to send numpy data from Python to Unity and not images from Unity to Python as in your example. Also, FMETP is for streaming my Unity game, right? That's not what I want to do in my project.

Comment: Oh right . Now I understand your question better. I will add another answer, hoping that will help !

Answer (score 0):

For sending your numpy array from python and receive it in unity, there are multiple ways. One of the simplest ways is that you convert your numpy array to string and send it through socket to unity. Then, convert it back to float in unity. A sample for sending string:

```
# python code
import socket 

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5050

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

msg = "sample string!"

sock.sendto(msg, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

//C# code
IPEndPoint anyIP = new 

IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), port);

byte[] data = client.Receive(ref anyIP); 

string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

---

Another way that may be a better approach (but I didn’t try it myself) is you can serialize your numpy python array. Since ndarray is a binary construct, you can use `ndarray.tobytes()` and then deserialize it in C#.

But for deserialization, pay attention to your numpy data types(int, float, etc.) and Endianness of your machine (little endian/ big endian)

An example for deserializing in C# (an array of bytes to array of doubles):

```
Buffer.BlockCopy();
```

You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952923/conversion-double-array-to-byte-array) question for more info.